# Ratchet PHP memory leak

Tags: php, memory-leaks, ratchet

I use Ratchet as a socket server for some browser-based game, and I noticed a very weird behaviour.

My application class implements WampServerInterface and I noticed that after 4-5 clients connect and disconnect (via autobahn.js) some memory (about 300KB) remains stuck. Then if another 7-8 clients connect and disconnect the memory usage will not increase. It will increase when 10-12 new clients connect and disconnect, so I have an impression that it reuses memory but still I have a fear that it could cause a memory leak, when many clients connect to the server.

Then I decided to do some testing, I made an application class that implements MessageComponentInterface (so that I can connect with the telnet). Here is the code that launches the server:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'bootstrap.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use AsterMedia\Games\Socket;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Socket(),
    9090,
    '127.0.0.1'
);

$server->run();

?>
```

My application class is very simple and it looks like this:

```
    <?php

    namespace AsterMedia\Games;

    use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
    use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

    class Socket implements MessageComponentInterface {

        public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

            echo "Client disconnected" . $this->getMemoryUsage() . PHP_EOL;

        }

        public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {

            echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        }

        public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

            echo "Client connected" . $this->getMemoryUsage() . PHP_EOL;

        }

        public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {

            echo $msg . PHP_EOL;
        }

        private function getMemoryUsage() {

            return sprintf('[Memory usage (currently) %dKB/ (max) %dKB]', round(memory_get_usage(true) / 1024), memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024);
        }   


    }
```

Finally, I made a bash script that connects and disconnects in an endless loop:

```
    while true
    do
    echo "connect"
    exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9090
    exec 3<&-
    echo "disconnect"
    sleep 1
    done
```

After running the bash script, I noticed the same behavior - after a few cycles, the memory usage increases.

Is this issue related to Ratchet (or React) or this is simply PHP's issue? I forgot to mention that I use PHP 5.5.3 with GC enabled.

Comment: WampServerInterface, does that mean you're on Windows? Your script indicates otherwise. It'd be good to also specify which OS you're using.

Comment: I don't use Windows. I use Linux Mint 16 with Apache2 web server. When I say WampServerInterface, I refer to http://socketo.me/api/class-Ratchet.Wamp.WampServerInterface.html 
I use WebSocket Application Messaging Protocol (WAMP) which wraps my application class (class name is Socket). My application class  implements WampServerInterface... I believe it has nothing to do with the OS

Comment: That was the original setup, when I noticed this memory issue and I decided not to use WAMP and use IoServer only (http://socketo.me/docs/server), just to be 100% sure that the memory usage increases even when I make telnet connections...

Comment: If you are into PHP, you could also try Truway (a PHP WAMP v2 implementation) together with Crossbar.io (a WAMP v2 router): http://crossbar.io/docs/Getting-started-with-PHP/ - This is how an application component looks like https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar/blob/master/crossbar/crossbar/templates/hello/php/client.php

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'd rather keep using Ratchet, because it has some features like SessionProvider (to share session with my symfony2 website) etc.

Answer (score 4):

By default WampServer does not free Topics once they are empty. Ratchet v0.3.2 introduced a new feature to change this. Topic objects now have a property called autoDelete that if set to true will destroy the Topic once the number of subscribers has reached 0.

```
public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    $topic->autoDelete = true;
}
```

The reason the reference is held was originally a (poor) design decision. autoDelete, instead of automatically freeing the Topic, was implemented because the change caused backwards compatibility breaks and bug if user land code kept reference to Topics (assuming unique object by id).

By setting autoDelete to true you will eventually notice your memory consumption go down once the GC runs.

Comment: Just one thing, I think gc_collect_cycles() should force GC to free the memory... Where do you think would be the most appropriate place to put that function (for testing) so that I can see the improvement in memory freeing with v0.3.2 and autoDelete?

Comment: The onClose handler is the best place to run `gc_collect_cycles()`

Answer (score 0):

Its the way php streams work internally. They buffer everything, and once a buffer grows it isn't shrunken until the script is closed. unset()'ing will clear the buffered data, but the buffer itself still exists (just in case more connections/messages come). They can grow very large, and can be a security/stability problem if you don't limit frame size (such as if someone trys to send a 1+ gig file)